# How do i add an icon to QComboBox in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to add an icon with text into the `QComboBox` in Qt, how can I implement it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Update: based on **Qt 5.13** (released 2019) there us a dedicated API for this:

```
void QComboBox::addItem(const QIcon &icon, const QString &text)
```

Or if you want to specify an index:

```
void QComboBox::insertItem ( int index, const QString & text)
void QComboBox::setItemIcon ( int index, const QIcon & icon )
```

All credit for this update goe to user [Soyal7](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9114655/soyal7) who suggested the edit. The former response, which still applies especially for **older versions**, was:

*You can use the following APIs:*

```
void QComboBox::insertItem ( int index, const QString & text, const QVariant & userData = QVariant() )
void QComboBox::setItemIcon ( int index, const QIcon & icon )
```

*http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#insertItem

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#setItemIcon*

*As for the code snippet it's as easy as this:*

```
void AddItem(QComboBox* combo, QString itemName, QIcon* icon)
{
    combo->insertItem(0, itemName);
    combo->setItemIcon(0, *icon);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply do (Qt5), for example:

```
   QIcon icon = QIcon::fromTheme("edit-undo");
   QString label = "foo";
   combo->addItem( icon, label );
```