# Qt Add non-square icon to QComboBox

Tags: c++, qt

How do I add a non-square Icon to a `QComboBox` item?

For instance, adding a regular square `QIcon` is accomplished by something like this, [How do i add an icon to QComboBox in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253976/how-do-i-add-an-icon-to-qcombobox-in-qt)

But I want to add an image of, say, 128 * 32 pixels

Comment: what happens if you use the same method? is it rescaled badly?

Comment: @IceFire Yes it's scaled to square

Comment: well, there is the method `QComboBox::setIconSize` which is the maximum size an icon can have. According to documentation, smaller icons are not scaled up

Comment: I have tested adding 128x128 icon and 128x32 (first image cropped) and the results is next. No rescaling occurs to me (Qt 5.7 used)

Test: http://i.imgur.com/le95yMK.png

Comment: @jgorosdev I got the problem: `setIconSize` shall be called before adding the items and icons...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that the call to `QComboBox::setIconSize()` shall be done BEFORE adding the actual items / icons (with `QComboBox::addItem(QIcon&, QString&)`